Как получить все GET запросы которые выполняются при загрузке сайта с помощью Firefox | selenium 4.18.1 (Python 3.9.10 AMD X64)
Помогите пожалуйста, подскажите как написать функцию которая будет(или она уже есть) отображать все GET запросы которые выполняет сайт. О каких запросах я говорю? Firefox > Инструменты веб-разработчика (Ctrl + Shift + I) > Сеть.
Вот пример:
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
driver = Firefox()
driver.get('example.com')
def allGetRequests():
    # ... Тут мы получаем список как в инструментах разработчика (Заголовки, Запрос, Ответ ...)
allGetRequests()


https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/
